# Import excel sheets as individual dataframes into R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, xlconnect, readxl

I have an excel file with 48 sheets, I used this code to read multiple sheets:

```
lst <- lapply(1:48, function(i) read_excel("my_file.xlsx", sheet = i))
```

`lst` has the information, but I would like to create individual dataframes in R. So, I would like to create 48 tables. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `readxl` package:

```r
library(readxl)
```

```r
my_sheet_names <- excel_sheets("my_file.xlsx")
my_sheets <- lapply(my_sheet_names, function(x) read_excel("my_file.xlsx", sheet = x))
names(my_sheets) <- my_sheet_names
```

This will give you a list of dataframes, each will be one of your sheets. You can then save them as individual dataframes if desired:

```r
list2env(my_sheets, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: I'm curious if there's a more tidy way to do this? Condense it all into one line with pipes?

Comment: @spops Use purrr::map functions. Also you can pass anything through pipes, and make it a one-liner.